# Can I have 2 Launch Images on xcasset?

Tags: ios, xcasset, launchimage

I have a Images.xcasset with 2 diferent Launch Images:

LaunchImage and LaunchImage2. In the Launch Images Source I choose Launch Images.

Then, in AppDelegate inside didFinishLaunchingWithOptions i have the folowing code:

```
splashView= [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds])];

    NSMutableArray *images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage"]];
    [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage2"]];

    [self.window addSubview:splashView];
    [self.window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
    splashView.animationImages = images;
    splashView.animationDuration = 2;
    splashView.animationRepeatCount = 1;
    [splashView startAnimating];
```

This is giving me an error when trying to retrieve LaunchImage2 . I suspect that is because it is not copied to the bundle. It's not supposed to be should copy all images that are within the xcasset ?

The error I'm getting is the following:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

Comment: you can't place two LaunchImages on xcasset. see this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html

Comment: you can do by using removing launch image and place a view with Screen image of your choice over first viewcontroller.

Comment: It should work, what error are you getting ?

Comment: Why don't you use the LaunchScreen.Storyboard ?

Comment: The problem is that I want to do is this: The application loads an image in the launch screen, and then by an animation , I keep the same visible image a few seconds , then change to a different one , but I need that second image is of the proper size .

Comment: So why don't you use the LaunchScreen.sotryboard ? You can create two UIImageView, hide the second one, animate the first one programmatically, show the second one and hide the first one o.O

Comment: Because launch XIB and launch storyboard does not work in lower versions than iOS 8.

Comment: anyway using LaunchScreen.storyboard when the app finishes loading, the main storyboard automatically be charged and lose control of the launch screen not ?